# update-manager crashes when I upgrade to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, update-manager

running update-manager results in a crash with this error:

```
** (do-release-upgrade:11138): WARNING **: Failed to load shared library 'libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37' referenced by the typelib: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: wl_proxy_marshal_constructor_versioned
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/types.py:205: Warning: cannot derive 'DistUpgrade+ReleaseNotesViewerWebkit+ReleaseNotesViewerWebkit' from non-derivable parent type 'void'
  _gobject.type_register(cls, namespace.get('__gtype_name__'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 169, in <module>
    fetcher.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeFetcherCore.py", line 275, in run
    if not self.showReleaseNotes():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeFetcher.py", line 62, in showReleaseNotes
    res = self._try_show_release_notes_webkit()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeFetcher.py", line 72, in _try_show_release_notes_webkit
    from .ReleaseNotesViewerWebkit import ReleaseNotesViewerWebkit
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/ReleaseNotesViewerWebkit.py", line 39, in <module>
    class ReleaseNotesViewerWebkit(WebKit.WebView):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 213, in __init__
    super(GObjectMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dict_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 193, in __init__
    cls._type_register(cls.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 205, in _type_register
    _gobject.type_register(cls, namespace.get('__gtype_name__'))
RuntimeError: could not create new GType: DistUpgrade+ReleaseNotesViewerWebkit+ReleaseNotesViewerWebkit (subclass of void)
```

I've had issues with this before resulting in me not being able to run the control center but I fixed that by using an older version of the problematic file. neither the new file or the old file works with this however and I feel that I have to find the source of my issues this time instead of a cheap workoaround. I have no clue of where to even begin. I've tried to repair the package but it simply states that it allready have the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a distribution upgrade first ($ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade) and do you have update-manager-core installed. The dist-upgrade will not upgrade you to a new version (16 to 18). It manages the more complicated upgrades in your current version where things may have changed in the background. Maybe then you can upgrade to a new version.

Comment: everything was up to date and it didn't do anything. And the update-manager-core was allready up to date allready.

Comment: You have declared a symbol but not defined it. It seems that this means you've installed two programs which share the same dependencies that are not actually sharing. This is more advanced than I am. Good luck.